# Parent object type hinting in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to type hint for a specific parent object in PHP:

I've current got a standard base object class:

```
class stdObject
{

   private $var;

   public function setVar($var)
   {
     $this->var = $var;
     return $this;
   }
}
```

And I have a class object that extends this:

```
class valObject extends stdObject
{
}
```

In a PHP function, I want to be able to type hint so that the function can expect any object that has a parent of `stdObject`, so sending in `valObject` would work but not `anyOldObject`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes, what you've descrived is *exactly* what type hinting is for. Here is the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

Answer (score 4):

You can by using the parent type :

```
function test(stdObject $obj) {
  // ...
}
```

If you don't want to have a pure stdObject as parameter, but only an object that inherit stdObject, you should put your stdObject class abstract or create an interface.

Answer (score 3):

Type hinting works with the implementation chain, so this is valid:

```
public function fnc(stdObject $obj)
```

This will accept any object that extends from stdObject including valObject. It also works with interfaces